# Finding virtual memory address of variable on osx

Tags: c, macos, mono, dynamic-linking, mach-o

Consider the following code in mono/domain.c:

```
static MonoDomain *mono_root_domain = NULL;
   ...
MonoDomain* mono_get_root_domain (void)
{
        return mono_root_domain;
}
```

My task is to read the struct data pointed by the mono_root_domain pointer in runtime from another process. (Attaching, reading, locating dylibs, etc. from this other process is solved already)

Looking into the generated libmono dylib I can find the corresponding symbol:

[image: _mono_root_domain symbol]

This symbol points to the address of 0x2621A8 which in the local relocation section (__DATA, __bss):

[image: local_relocation]

This points to the address of 0x1A7690 (__TEXT, __symbol_stub):
[image: indirect stup]

The target is
[image: target]

so 0x1A7DF8 (__TEXT, __stub_helper):
[image]

At this point I am completely lost of how to retrieve the actual pointer to the MonoDomain struct. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons and to prevent buffer overflow attacks and other exploits, you can't know that, because of a security measure called PIE or ASLR (address space layout randomization). However, this can be disabled for debugging purposes. LLDB and GDB do/did it in order to debug executables. The way this can be done with a CLI app is as follows:

1. Copy or download this python script from GitHub
   https://github.com/thlorenz/chromium-build/blob/master/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py
2. Save the python script, for example, next to your executable
3. If so, open Terminal and `cd` to where your executable is
4. enter `chmod +x ./change_mach_o_flags.py` to make the script executable
5. enter `./change_mach_o_flags.py --no-pie ./YourExecutable`

Now the addresses of your executable should not be randomized anymore. Because of that, to calculate the addresses of your static / global variables is possible. To do that, do the following in Terminal (I am assuming you are using a 64-bit machine):

1. `otool -v -l ./YourExecutable | open -f`(this will generate a file text with the commands inside your executable of how to layout DATA, TEXT, etc. in memory)
2. Look for the section you are interested in. Look at the `addr` field. If it contains let's say `0x0000000100001020` then the variable will be placed exactly there with ASLR disabled.

I am not sure if this works with dylibs but you can try it. Now I ran out of time, but I can try at home and see if this is doable with dylibs.